# Using prototype JavaScript - best practice

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Currently I am working in a project where we are writing Object Oriented JavaScript. In this project I have seen two different ways of defining a class:

1: Declare functions at once on the prototype

```
My.Namespace.ClassName = function(param1, param2) {
   this.member1 = param1;
   this.member2 = param2;
};

My.Namespace.ClassName.prototype = {
   myFunction1: function() {
      return this.member1 + " " + this.member2;
   },

   myFunction2: function(param1) {
      this.member3 = paraml;
   }
};
```

2:Prepare each function individual on the prototype

```
My.Namespace.ClassName = function(param1, param2) {
   this.member1 = param1;
   this.member2 = param2;
};

My.Namespace.ClassName.prototype.myFunction1 = function() {
   return this.member1 + " " + this.member2;
};

My.Namespace.ClassName.prototype.myFunction2 = function(param1) {
   this.member3 = paraml;
};
```

Is there any difference in how JavaScript behaves based on the two given examples or is it only a style difference?

Personally I haven't seen any behavior difference but I have the feeling that there must be a subtle difference which I am currently missing.

Besides that. I would like to know whether this is a common practice or are there much better ways to define classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a subtle difference. In the first method, when you overwrite the prototype, there was a property there that is now lost. That's the `constructor`, which points back to your function. The constructor allows you to recreate the type of object that it is.

You can easily get it back and so use the first method by manually setting it:

```
My.Namespace.ClassName.prototype = {
   myFunction1: function() {
      return this.member1 + " " + this.member2;
   },

   myFunction2: function(param1) {
      this.member3 = paraml;
   },
   constructor: My.Namespace.ClassName
};
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean with _In the first method, when you overwrite the prototype, there was a property there that is now lost_. Do you mean that there is a difference in the `My.Namespace.ClassName.constructor` before and after calling `var obj = new My.Namespace.ClassName("value1", "value2")`?

Comment: No - `My.Namespace.ClassName.prototype` comes with a `constructor` property. When you overwrite the prototype, the constructor is lost.

Comment: Accepted but one question though: Can I combine both styles or will that cause somewhere problems?

Comment: If you use the code here to add back the constructor property, so there's no reason why you can't then add more properties to the prototype like any other object.

Comment: Is there one way considered as a better practice than the other one ?